# require.js define dependency only if existant

Tags: javascript, requirejs, dependency-management, amd

How can I define a dependency only if it exists? I want to use the object 'myObject' only if it already exists/has been created.

```
define(['dependencyOne', 'dependencyTwo', 'myObject'], function(depOne, depTwo, myObj) { ...
```

Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You should probably clarify what you're trying to achieve; in the example above `myObject` would be dependency name. It's expected to point at another **module** that returns an object; that object would be available through the `myObj` reference. What do you mean by "dependency (...) exists?". RequireJS guarantees that `myObj` will be created before function body is executed. More details in the [RequireJS documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep)

Comment: I am now checking like this

`if (typeof(myObj) != 'undefined') {myObj.reposition();}`

and this seems to work for me

Comment: Puzzled as to why you would request a module that might not exist? If it wasn't an empty file you would see a 404 error.